# how to get request in express.js without changing current page?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

in my express server when I click on upload button or download button I want that my server work with file system(fs) without changing web page. how to implement this code in JS?

```
let express = require('express');
let Fs = require('fs');
let path = require('path');
let URL = require('url');
let app = express();
let router = express.Router();

const port = 2020;

app.use(express.static('Programs'));
app.use('/', router);

router.get('/' , (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/views/UiOfServer.html'));
});

router.get('/todo/download' , (req, res) => {
    res.send("download page");
});

router.get('/todo/upload' , (req, res) => {
    res.send("upload page");
});

app.listen(port, (err, res) => {
    if(err){
        console.log(`Server Error: ${err}`);
    }
    else{
        console.log(`server started on ${port}`);
    }
})
```

Comment: if there is another methed instead of router please tell me.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the current page in the browser to change or refresh when clicking a button you should use AJAX.

You should use upload and download endpoints as apis and call these apis from your webpage.

You can use libraries such as jquery, axios, fetch, etc to make your job easier

Example in jquery

```
$.get('/todo/download').done(response => console.log(response))
```

Comment: this is a task for me that I can not use any libraries or framworks except node.js express.js and pure JS

Comment: but it is useful thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that you don't want the server to read and write continuously? If it's true, try it

```
fs.readFileSync(your_data_url);
```

it should be at the top (maybe after `let router = express.Router();`) because it is synchronous, and it only runs once when you load web page

Comment: actually I have some data in my web page and in web page I have two buttons, upload download button

Comment: when click on upload button server load data from txt file to web page

Comment: when click on download button server write data from web page to txt file

Comment: now when I click on these buttons my url and current web page changes but I just want to call a function for work with fs and don't change web page.